# What do ants do with human finger nails?

Tags: human-biology, entomology, food, ant

There is place in my house where I cut my nails. Here, there is an ant hole where an ant colony is seen.

Whenever I cut my nails from here, they take my nails inside their hole. I was wondering what they do with them.

Do they protect their houses with them or feed them to their young ones?

Comment: How fast are your nails growing that you cut them daily? (I cut my finger nails about weekly, the toe nails even less often.)

Comment: Me too cut weekly. I was just kidding in comment to MattDMo's answer. :)

Comment: If nothing else, they can probably make  a throne for their queen out of this flexible material!

Comment: That is gross....

Comment: Based on the confliction of the two answers, can you take a photo of the ant closely so we can identify which ant it is?

Comment: Can't see the image..!

Comment: But please leave out the nails on the macro. If you do close-up those nails I will close-vote and bribe the moderators ;-)

Comment: @AliceD Gross for you, food for them. :D

Comment: My pet ant found this page by googling `what can we ants do with all these fingernails we've collected`.

Comment: @Imprisoned It's not gross. It's called curiosity to know science behind. :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are [a number of papers](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=keratin+metabolism+fungi) studying the ability of fungi to metabolize [keratin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keratin), the primary structural component of nails (as well as skin and hair). Ants are also known to [cultivate fungi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant%E2%80%93fungus_mutualism) for nutrients, so this may simply be a case where the ants are bringing food for their "farm animals."

Comment: Nice explanation. Thanks :) Now, I will feed the hungry ants daily :D

Comment: It's true that some fungi can break down keratin, and that some ants cultivate fungi, but these two facts do not imply that this is what is going on here.

Comment: Do you have any evidence at all to support this? I agree that it makes sense as a possibility but that's not enough for accepting it as fact.

Comment: @terdon I never claimed to represent it as fact. The OP didn't state what part of the world s/he was in, and it's impossible to identify the ants in the picture. I stated "*this may simply be a case ...*", not "*this is exactly what's going on, and no other explanation is possible.*" The other answer is just as much of a guess as this one. One couldn't know for certain unless they were on location, excavated the anthole, and studied the whole situation *in situ*.

Comment: Fair enough, I only posted that comment because your answer has been accepted. It is a very intriguing suggestion if true but it's not really all that likely. I was just hoping you might have a reference to support it is all.

Answer (score 33):

I believe that MattDMo's hypothesis is incorrect.  Only one group of ants, the Attini tribe, cultivates fungus as a food source.  This group is exclusively a New World group, thought to have originated in the Amazon rainforest and spread out from there.  I see from your profile that you are located in India, which is outside the range of the fungus-cultivating ants.

So if the ants aren't using your fingernails for fungus cultivation, what are they doing with them?  Fingernails are primarily composed of keratin, a very tough protein which ants cannot digest.  However, it is likely that the clippings also contain materials like dead skin, nail fungus, or other organic substances that the ants can eat, making them worthwhile for the ants to collect.

References:

- U.G. Mueller, T.R. Schultz, C.R. Currie, R.M.M. Adams, & D. Malloch (2001). "[The origin of the attine ant-fungus mutualism](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2664003)". *Quarterly Review of Biology* **76** (2): 169–197. doi:[10.1086/393867](http://dx.doi.org/10.1086/393867)

Comment: Maybe fungi are on the nail digesting keratin partially on the ground so that ants can eat partially digested nail.

Comment: Maybe the ants are stupid and don't realise fingernails are useless to them. They could smell delicious to an ant but not be usable.

Comment: Maybe the ants are *really* smart and need the fingernails to complete the human they are building.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that the *only* cultivating ants are in the New World?

Comment: @MattDMo, 10 second Google search found [this](http://bioold.science.ku.dk/drnash/atta/pages/Leafcut.html).

Comment: @MattDMo Added a source, can be read for free on JSTOR but requires registration.

Comment: @JasonC  This hypothesis and several others have been proposed [here](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?250299-Why-ant-gather-nails).